# Problemas com o GIT

Tags: git

Eu tinha alguns arquivos modificados no meu `branch` local, porem fiquei muito tempo sem atualizar o repositório- erro meu.

Bom mas o que acontece é que eu não fiz o `commit` dos arquivos e fui obrigado a dar um `reset` em todo o meu `branch`, para conseguir atualizar o meu repositório.

**O problema começa aqui:**

Tinha muitas modificações muitos programas feitos prontos para serem enviados ao servidor e eu não faço ideia de como recuperar arquivos no meu `branch` local que nem ao menos foram feitos `commits` deles..

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Você chegou a dar `git add` nos arquivos antes de dar o reset?

Comment: Aqui tem varias soluções possiveis, dependendo do seu caso (com commits, com adds, com arquivos novos, etc): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard

Comment: Não dei git add antes do reset nem nada, os arquivos estavam como status de modificado.

Comment: Se você não adicionou no repositório você não irá conseguir recuperar esses arquivos! Deletado é deletado... a não ser que esteja na lixeira da sua máquina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os arquivos estavam com status "modificado", eles já existiam no `index` do Git, o que é uma boa notícia. Você pode recuperar todos as revisões de arquivos que foram salvas mas abandonadas com o comando

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
```

Esse comando cria duas pastas dentro do seu diretorio `.git`: `.git/lost-found/commits` e `.git/lost-found/other` e salva nessas pastas todos os arquivos que entraram no histórico do GIT quando você salvou, mas que não foram utilizados, não tem relação no índice atual do projeto.

Dependendo de há quanto tempo essa cópia local vem sendo usada isso pode ser algumas centenas de arquivos, mas é grande a chance de você recuperar pelo menos uma parte do seu trabalho ali.

Do manual:

> ```
> git-fsck - Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database
>
> --lost-found -  Write dangling objects into .git/lost-found/commit/ 
> or .git/lost-found/other/, depending on type. If the object is a blob, 
> the contents are written into the file, rather than its object name.
> ```